# Upper and lower indices postponed

Tags: math-mode, greek

I have a question regarding upper and lower indices.

If I write something like

```
$A = \hat{\tau}^1_2$
```

the upper and lower indices are postponed in such a way that the lower index is a bit more left compared to the upper index.

But I want them to be among themselves.

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: That's the commonest practice, in order not to leave holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

workaround: insert empty {}

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$A = \hat{\tau}{}^1_2$

\end{document}
```